# Import Excel data in to mysql with PHP

Tags: php, excel

Can somebody send me PHP code which will read an excel file and write the data of that excel file into database. It should also read multiple tabs of that excel file and perform the same operation.

Thanks

Comment: If your question is: Can somebody `do something`? The answer must be yes, someone can

Answer (score 9):

We will not send you the codes.

We can, instead, point you at helpful libraries that you can use. Check out [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/), it can work with XSLX files.  There's also [php-excel](http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/), which claims to be more lightweight than PHPExcel.

Incidentally, these were the top results when searching Google for `php excel`

Comment: For the future reader, php-excel converts *from* php *to* excel.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I prefer using `ODBC`, which lets you treat the excel file as a database and query against it...

```
$file = realpath($file);
$dir = dirname($file);
$dsn  = 'Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DriverId=790;Dbq='.$file.';';
$dsn .= 'DefaultDir='.$dir.';';
$connection = odbc_connect($dsn, '', '');
if ($connection === false) {
    die('Could not connect to Excel File');
}
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1]';
$result = odbc_exec($connection, $sql);
if ($result === false) {
    die('Query Error: ['.odbc_error($connection).'] '.
        odbc_errormsg($connection));
}
$rows = array();
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

The cool part of this, is that Excel automatically pulls the column name from the first row of the file...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a PEAR package Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer.
[link text](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

**How to get data from Excel:**

http://www.eephp.com/

http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/reading-xls-with-php-en/

**How to store data into database if you are using mysql:**

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_insert.asp